# How do you find out if a user has installed my app?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I need to work out if a user has my app installed so I can display a slighlty different page. How do you do this?

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you'd want to capture their Facebook user ID in your own database when they originally install your app.  When they come back, you can compare the current users Facebook user ID with your database to see if you find any matches.

If you don't have a database, you can always check on a user permissions using the Graph API.  You can find the code here: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/495

This will give you back an array that looks something like this:

```
Array ( [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [installed] => 1 [bookmarked] => 1 ) ) )
```

In this case, the user has it installed and has bookmarked it.  Now that you know that, you can display a slightly different page.

Answer (score 0):

You do this by using the FB JavaScript API and querying if the user is logged in. If it is (to you) it will have your app installed.